Proxy authentication required for nuget.sitecore.com
When I am trying the restore the nuget packages in VS 2022, I am getting the "Proxy authentication required" error for nuget.sitecore.com.

Sitecore packages download access are blocked by the network. After enabling the access, I haven't received the popup.
https://artifacts.sitecore.com/public/resources/nuget/Sitecore.Kernel/10.2.0/Sitecore.Kernel.10.2.0.nupkg

The "Proxy authentication required" error typically occurs when Visual Studio is unable to authenticate through your network's proxy server. Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:

Restart Visual Studio: Sometimes, simply restarting Visual Studio can prompt a proxy authentication dialog where you can enter your credentials.
Use Fiddler: You can use Fiddler to automatically authenticate your proxy. Configure Fiddler as your upstream proxy and restart Visual Studio.

3.Allowlist URLs: Ensure that the following URLs are added to your proxy's allowlist to unblock Visual Studio's network resources:
*.windows.net
*.microsoftonline.com
*.visualstudio.microsoft.com
*.microsoft.com
*.live.com1

If these steps don't resolve the issue, you might need to check with your network administrator to ensure that your proxy settings are correctly configured.

What credentials I need to pass in Fiddler?
How to Allowlist these URLs?

You need to pass your work credentails or system credenatials and for Allowlist is on your proxy server settings.
